# Using assertThrows from JUnit5 in Groovy

Tags: groovy, junit, assert, junit5

When using Java and assertThrows:

```
public static <T extends Throwable> T assertThrows(Class<T> expectedType, Executable executable)
```

we can write simple lambda function:

```
@Test
void testExpectedException() {

  Assertions.assertThrows(NumberFormatException.class, () -> {
    Integer.parseInt("One");
  });

}
```

How we can do this in Groovy?

I was trying something like:

```
@Test
void testExpectedException() {

  assertThrows(NumberFormatException.class, {
    Integer.parseInt("One");
  }())

}
```

but the error is thrown and not caught:

```
java.lang.format.NumberFormatException: For ....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one mistake in your test method. Instead of coercing a closure to an `Executable` type, you passed a result of calling a closure. The correct syntax is:

```
@Test
void testExpectedException() {
  assertThrows(NumberFormatException.class, {
    Integer.parseInt("One");
  })
}
```

You can make it even "groovier" with:

```
@Test
void testExpectedException() {
  assertThrows(NumberFormatException) {
    Integer.parseInt("One")
  }
}
```

This second example uses popular Groovy idiom - when the method's last parameter is a closure, you can put it outside the parenthesis. It looks like a code block, but it is just a closure passed as a second parameter to the method.

In the Java example, you have used a lambda expression passed as an instance of `Executable` functional interface. Groovy's equivalent for that (at least in Groovy 2.x version - support for lambda expressions is added in Groovy 3) is closure coercion to SAM type (single abstract method). The above example shows how to define an instance of the `Executable` type with a closure. If you put `()` after the closure closing brace, you make a shortcut to a `call()` method execution. This method executes closure's body.